# Validate correct sending GCM

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to verify that a message has been sent correctly.

I have this code:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
     die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
}

// Close connection
curl_close($ch);

return $result;
```

I just want to check that the message has been sent correctly to the Google server (not to destination user), to show a message like "Message Sent".

I have to work with the result array, specifically with the success field (check if si is greater than 1).

How would you implement that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not enough to know that `success` > 1. You need to know that there are no failures (`failure` = 0), and if there are any failures, you need to check the error code name, and handle the error :

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($result);
if ($jsonArray->failure > 0) {
  if(!empty($jsonArray->results)) {
    for($i=0; $i<count($jsonArray->results);$i++){
        if(isset($jsonArray->results[$i]->error)){
            if($jsonArray->results[$i]->error == "<SomeErrorCodeName>") {
                // handle specific error code name
            }
            // check for other error code names ...
        }
    }
  }
} else {
  // no failures
}
```